# Using .htaccess to redirect domain.co.uk/index.html to www.domain.co.uk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have noticed that search engines have been crawling both the domain.co.uk and www.domain.co.uk versions of a web site that I've recently developed. 
Using .htaccess I have been able to setup http 301 redirects so that:

- http://domain.co.uk is redirected to http://www.domain.co.uk

and

- http://www.domain.co.uk/index.html is redirected to http://www.domain.co.uk

However:

- http://domain.co.uk/index.html does not get redirected to http://www.domain.co.uk as I would expect. Instead the redirect goes to: http://www.domain.co.uk/http://www.domain.co.uk/

The contents of my .htaccess are (obviously I have replaced my domain to simplify matters):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.co.uk [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,nc]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I know I am probably missing something obvious but please could someone help me get the final redirect to http://www.domain.co.uk working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of your rule set is working fine, the missing www. is added correctly. For the second part you only need a simple rule to remove the index.html without using any additional condition:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.domain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

I think this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks jCoder, that makes sense to me but http://domain.co.uk/index.html redirects to a domain marketplace site instead now (www.sedo.co.uk), any ideas?

Comment: I think this is something beyond the scope of the .htaccess rewrite question. I thought that you used that domain name as a replacement for your real domain (something like example.com). If you are the owner of that domain, then you could check the whois entry or contact your webhosting company.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes I was still using domain.co.uk as a replacement for my real domain, just to make the example simpler. I own the domain in question and am just trying to get all posible routes to the homepage to redirect to www.mydomain.co.uk as I appears to be suffering from diluted search results currently.

Comment: Ok for some reason clearing my browser cache appeared to use the latest .htaccess settings, your changes above cause a redirect loop unfortunately.

Comment: That is interesting (because I tried it with an own domain). Anyway, a redirect loop _might_ occur if the file that is called for '/' itself does an external redirect to 'index.html', which depends on the implementational details of your page. If possible, check the access.log file for the domain to see where the redirects are caused.

Comment: Hmm well the access log doesn't tell me a lot besides showing a lot of GET requests for www.mydomain.co.uk all immediately subsequent to each other (obviously the redirect loop). I think I might just have to live with the 3 out of 4 home page paths redirecting correctly.

Comment: If it is okay, then I'd stick with it too. Otherwise you could set the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directive, but this is only possible in server configuration (and not .htaccess), and that log gets big and unreadable very fast, so it's a lot of work investigating.

Comment: @jCoder: the `NC` flags you placed there are pointless! The only place where the `NC` flag is needed is in the last row where you did not place it: `RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.domain.co.uk/ [R=301,NC,L]`. As is now if someone asks for `http://www.domain.co.uk/INDEX.HTML` the `INDEX.HTML` is not removed.

Comment: @Marco: You're right. I only changed the "essential" part of the rules in my answer, and the NCs remained where the original poster has put them.